# PDF.js crashes WebKit2WebProcess.exe in Safari

Tags: safari, webkit, pdf.js

I'm embedding PDF.js using

```
<iframe src="/pathto/viewer.html?file=/pathto/example.pdf" class="pdf"></iframe>
```

The css I'm adding to it is only changing the width and height. I'm using Windows 7 64-bit and the latest Safari as of a couple of days ago from the apple site: 5.1.7.

Any ideas any one?

Comment: 5.1.7 is really old version, I don't think apple is going support windows version

Comment: Do you think it's worth supporting a the windows version then?